# UISearchBar and TableViewController

Tags: ios7, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchbardisplaycontrol

I had a TableView which worked perfectly.
Now I have included a search in `TableView` with the `SearchBar component and Display ViewController`.
I want the search to be made based on the label that is populated by NSArray _rotulos.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *rotulos;
```

I fill the content in my viewDidLoad method (there is more objects, but here is just an example)

```
_rotulos = @[@"Item 1", @"Item 2", @"Item 3", @"Block 1", @"Block 2",@"Block 3"];
```

I populate in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell";
    TableCell *cell = (TableCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    //Configure the cell...
       if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[TableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

    long row = [indexPath row];

    cell.rotuloLabel.text    = _rotulos[row];
    cell.descricaoLabel.text = _vinicola[row];
    cell.uvaLabel.text       = _uva[row];

    return cell;
}
```

This works fine. 
I have the problem when a click in the SearchBar and start typing.

Here is the code that make this search.

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"_rotulos contains[c] %@", searchText];
    searchResults = [recipes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
            scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}
```

I have the problem in the line `NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"_rotulos contains[c] %@", searchText];`
This is my output **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFConstantString 0x243c8> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key _rotulos.'**

I follow this [Tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/search-bar-tutorial-ios7/) but in my case _rotulos is not a property of some classe, is a NSArray.

How i fix that?
Sorry if a forget to post something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't form this filter using `predicateWithFormat:`. Use `predicateWithBlock:` or create the filtered array in some other way (i.e. not `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`).

Comment: How Can I do that?
I looking for some examples but i do not find it.

Comment: I don't know because I don't understand what you are trying to do. But look for example at this code: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch08p438searchableTable/ch21p718sections/RootViewController.m Look at the `filterData:` implementation to see how I form the filtered array for my table based on what the user types in the search field.

Comment: What I want to do is filter the NSArray _rotulos (that populates my TableView) store this filtered array in my NSArray _resultadosBusca and Reload my TableView with this new data.

Comment: I know. But I do not know on what _basis_ you want to filter that NSArray. However, I don't need to, because I'm not going to write your code for you. _Look at the code I pointed you at._ I am showing you exactly how this is done. You should easily be able to adapt that example.